# Почему Flutter приложение не запускается в Genymotion?

Tags: android, flutter, genymotion

При запуске Flutter-приложения в Genymotion приложение сразу вылетает с ошибкой. Пробовал версии андроида 5.1, 6, 7.1. Более новые версии не запускаются. Genymoton 3.2.0, ArchLinux. В логах запуска приложения нашел это:

```
** Activity starting: com.example.flutter_application_1
** ERROR: PROCESS CRASHED
processName: com.example.flutter_application_1
processPid: 4671
shortMsg: Native crash
longMsg: Native crash: Illegal instruction
timeMillis: 1614854399152
stack:
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:5.1/LMY47D/632:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 4671, tid: 4704, name: DartWorker  >>> com.example.flutter_application_1 <<<
signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xe2c3313a
    eax 3fffffff  ebx e2e10ac4  ecx 00000000  edx ffffffff
    esi c0000000  edi e10dbf80
    xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000002b
    eip e2c3313a  ebp e07feda8  esp e07fed70  flags 00010286

backtrace:
    #00 pc 0072d13a  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #01 pc 006f8e12  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #02 pc 006fa028  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #03 pc 0070129a  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #04 pc 006abf2e  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #05 pc 006aca6c  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #06 pc 006ac51f  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #07 pc 005cfafa  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #08 pc 0066aad4  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #09 pc 0066ac1c  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #10 pc 0066b2b3  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #11 pc 0066b624  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #12 pc 000012ab  <unknown>
    #13 pc 00001cc6  <unknown>
    #14 pc 0001792d  <unknown>
    #15 pc 00015867  <unknown>
    #16 pc 0001391f  <unknown>
    #17 pc 0001356f  <unknown>
    #18 pc 00013396  <unknown>
    #19 pc 00012c8d  <unknown>
    #20 pc 00012906  <unknown>
    #21 pc 00011daa  <unknown>
    #22 pc 00010aee  <unknown>
    #23 pc 00005f32  <unknown>
    #24 pc 000015a0  <unknown>
    #25 pc 00547c65  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #26 pc 00547a84  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #27 pc 005478f7  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #28 pc 00686661  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #29 pc 006863c7  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #30 pc 0069f57b  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #31 pc 0069f839  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #32 pc 006201d1  /data/app/com.example.flutter_application_1-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #33 pc 000211d8  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
    #34 pc 0001c559  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
    #35 pc 00013126  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
#
```

Пробовал Genymotion ARM Translation. Тоже самое.
Логи Flutter run:

```
[ +143 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[ +102 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 60bd88df915880d23877bfc1602e8ddcf4c4dd2a
[   +7 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git tag --points-at
60bd88df915880d23877bfc1602e8ddcf4c4dd2a
[  +23 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 60bd88df915880d23877bfc1602e8ddcf4c4dd2a
[        ] 2.0.0
[  +83 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +12 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +136 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +36 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] stable
[ +330 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[  +12 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +284 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +89 ms] List of devices attached
           192.168.57.104:5555    device transport_id:2
[  +10 ms] /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 shell getprop
[ +115 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +172 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +285 ms] Generating
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins
/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[ +145 ms] ro.hardware = vbox86
[        ] ro.build.characteristics = default
[  +91 ms] Initializing file store
[  +39 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +14 ms] complete
[  +10 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on 192.168.57.104:5555 in debug mode...
[  +11 ms] /home/artur/Flutter/sdk/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot
--sdk-root /home/artur/Flutter/sdk/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/
--incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata
--output-dill /tmp/flutter_tools.ZIJWLD/flutter_tool.NITZFI/app.dill --packages
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/.dart_tool/package_config.json
-Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation
--filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build/cache.dill.track.dill
[  +37 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
AndroidManifest.xml
[  +43 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
AndroidManifest.xml
[   +1 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1e
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="11" (Raw: "11")
               A: package="com.example.flutter_application_1" (Raw:
               "com.example.flutter_application_1")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1e
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xb
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1e
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: application (line=16)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="flutter_application_1" (Raw:
                 "flutter_application_1")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A:
                 android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactor
                 y" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=21)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity"
                   (Raw: "com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=35)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                     (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=45)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawabl
                     e" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
                   E: intent-filter (line=49)
                     E: action (line=50)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=52)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=59)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
[  +35 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 shell
-x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +19 ms] <- compile package:flutter_application_1/main.dart
[ +295 ms] --------- beginning of system
                    03-04 10:56:26.843 I/BootReceiver(  603): Copying
                    /data/tombstones/tombstone_08 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
[  +79 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[ +239 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                    Version 31.0.0-7110759
                    Installed as /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
[  +20 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[ +148 ms] Building APK
[ +225 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[  +20 ms] Using gradle from
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/android/gradlew.
[  +42 ms] /home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/android/gradlew mode: 33261
rwxr-xr-x.
[  +48 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/android/]
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget-platform=android-x86
-Ptarget=/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/lib/main.dart
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+2674 ms] Welcome to Gradle 6.7!
[  +12 ms] Here are the highlights of this release:
[        ]  - File system watching is ready for production use
[        ]  - Declare the version of Java your build requires
[   +3 ms]  - Java 15 support
[        ] For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/release-notes.html
[+8054 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[   +1 ms] [ +158 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git -c log.showSignature=false log
-n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +88 ms] [ +108 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[   +3 ms] [        ] 60bd88df915880d23877bfc1602e8ddcf4c4dd2a
[        ] [   +2 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git tag --points-at
60bd88df915880d23877bfc1602e8ddcf4c4dd2a
[  +22 ms] [  +81 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at
60bd88df915880d23877bfc1602e8ddcf4c4dd2a
[        ] [        ] 2.0.0
[ +168 ms] [ +116 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref
--symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] [  +39 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] [        ] origin/stable
[   +4 ms] [        ] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] [  +31 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +296 ms] [ +279 ms] executing: [/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +5 ms] [  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +5 ms] [        ] stable
[ +395 ms] [ +380 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[   +8 ms] [   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[   +8 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +6 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[  +13 ms] [  +28 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[  +16 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +4 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required,
skipping update.
[ +328 ms] [ +400 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +10 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[   +4 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] [   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +7 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[  +18 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +38 ms] [   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] [   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[ +194 ms] [ +260 ms] Initializing file store
[ +101 ms] [  +52 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[        ] [  +21 ms] kernel_snapshot: Starting due to {}
[        ] [  +47 ms] /home/artur/Flutter/sdk/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
/home/artur/Flutter/sdk/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot
--sdk-root /home/artur/Flutter/sdk/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/
--target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Ddart.vm.profile=false
-Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/.dart_tool/package_config.json --output-dill
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/.dart_tool/flutter_build/5adc445558245ccb3b4
55d9ca37a5b7c/app.dill --depfile
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/.dart_tool/flutter_build/5adc445558245ccb3b4
55d9ca37a5b7c/kernel_snapshot.d package:flutter_application_1/main.dart
[+30003 ms] [+29903 ms] kernel_snapshot: Complete
[+1193 ms] [+1255 ms] debug_android_application: Starting due to {}
[ +800 ms] [ +826 ms] debug_android_application: Complete
[+1101 ms] [+1107 ms] Persisting file store
[  +98 ms] [  +43 ms] Done persisting file store
[        ] [  +18 ms] build succeeded.
[   +1 ms] [  +25 ms] "flutter assemble" took 34 214ms.
[   +1 ms] [   +7 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 0ms
[        ] [   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +2 ms] [        ] exiting with code 0
[+1103 ms] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[  +89 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[ +197 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[ +800 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[  +99 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[  +99 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
[ +400 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[ +198 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[  +98 ms] > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[  +99 ms] > Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
[ +399 ms] > Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[+2700 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[ +199 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[   +3 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[+1293 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
[ +403 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
[ +896 ms] > Task :app:compressDebugAssets
[ +899 ms] > Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
[ +100 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[  +99 ms] > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
[ +201 ms] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[ +398 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
[        ] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
[+6099 ms] > Task :app:packageDebug
[ +800 ms] > Task :app:assembleDebug
[ +187 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with
Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See
https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 2s
[        ] 32 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 18 up-to-date
[ +441 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 64,1s)
[ +516 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory:
'/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk'/app.apk
[ +118 ms] calculateSha: reading file took 111us
[+1531 ms] calculateSha: computing sha took 1530us
[  +54 ms] ✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
[  +38 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
AndroidManifest.xml
[  +56 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1e
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="11" (Raw: "11")
               A: package="com.example.flutter_application_1" (Raw:
               "com.example.flutter_application_1")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1e
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xb
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1e
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw:
                 "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: application (line=16)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="flutter_application_1" (Raw:
                 "flutter_application_1")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A:
                 android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactor
                 y" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=21)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity"
                   (Raw: "com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=35)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                     (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=45)
                     A:
                     android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawabl
                     e" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
                   E: intent-filter (line=49)
                     E: action (line=50)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=52)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=59)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
[   +9 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on 192.168.57.104:5555.
[   +3 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 shell
am force-stop com.example.flutter_application_1
[ +751 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 shell
pm list packages com.example.flutter_application_1
[ +486 ms] package:com.example.flutter_application_1
[   +3 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 shell
cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.flutter_application_1.sha1
[ +103 ms] dc8b4ce7ed23137a5105f24666405792d8816429
[   +1 ms] Installing APK.
[   +2 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
[        ] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 install
-t -r /home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
[+9150 ms] Performing Push Install
                    /home/artur/Flutter/projects/flutter_application_1/build/app/outputs/flutte
                    r-apk/app.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 20.0 MB/s (51778112 bytes in
                    2.471s)
                        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk
                    Success
[   +1 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk... (completed in 9,2s)
[   +6 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 shell
echo -n c95263c5f70466134e3c944dd8b5e44ac8ef5865 >
/data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.flutter_application_1.sha1
[ +112 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 shell
-x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +91 ms] --------- beginning of main
           03-04 10:57:49.282 W/Zygote  ( 2465): createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing
           CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
[  +28 ms] executing: /home/artur/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.57.104:5555 shell
am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true
--ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
com.example.flutter_application_1/com.example.flutter_application_1.MainActivity
[+1134 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000
cmp=com.example.flutter_application_1/.MainActivity (has extras) }
```

Comment: какая ветка и версия флаттера?

Comment: stable, 2.0, на 1.22 было такое же, и на dev ветке то же самое

Comment: Где логи сборки? `flutter run --verbose`

Comment: добавил логи --verbose.

Comment: @piterow x86 не поддерживается на сколько я помню

Answer (score 0):

На текущий момент FLutter не поддерживает в `release` сборке архитектуру x86 (только в `debug`). Со списком поддерживаемых архитектур можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures).

Вы можете сделать сборку по [инструкции](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/JIT-Release-Modes), это будет `debug` версия с использованием JIT но в релизной сборке.